# Is it possible to test Windows 7 RC XP Mode under VMWare Workstation 6.5?

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-7, virtualization, windows

I am currently using VMWare Workstation 6.5 to test the Windows 7 RC build 7100, and am particularly interested in evaluating the new "XP Mode" feature.  However, since one of the prerequisites is hardware virtualization support, I am afraid this might not be possible under the isolation of a guest OS.  Is there a configuration option in VMWare to allow this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Win7 XP Mode only works if your CPU supports "VT" (or AMD's equivalent).

It's unlikely that VMWare Workstation will emulate or otherwise expose the VT feature to guest O/Ses running under virtualisation, such that the guest O/S's own virtualisation host will work.

Comment: That's my understanding too.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there might be a way to "bypass" the guest isolation of the VT feature somehow -- similar to how you can choose to use a real hard drive partition directly instead of a virtual drive within the VM -- but it appears you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using virtual box and it works fine combined with my hardware virtualisation.
Not sure about VMWare, but I should think it works there also, VMWare are generally on top of the latest virtualisation stuff.

Comment: the OP is asking about running a virtual O/S inside another virtual O/S.